# How to use uitableview inside error under uitextfield and validate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, error-handling, tableview

I used table view and xib one text field in section. I one uilable in xib how to hide and show it for error message in table view.

Comment: Do you want to display error message on tableView ?

Comment: You can use the own UITextField to put a text.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your xib and storyboard, so that you can get appropriate solution within time.

Comment: If you want to show/hide some components, probably you are better off using a stack view to make things easier to implement. I wouldnt recommend stack view when there are way too many cells as it has its own performance issues and all, but in this case I think you can have one vertical stack with a text & error label. When you get an invalid input, just unhide that error label and reload table.

Comment: I think OP wants to show error text under textField. If email is invalid then Some error text shows under Email textField and when Email field has valid email then no error text show. Something like this : https://github.com/iDhaval/DTTextField

Comment: Im using xib in that I have create one text field, I call the textfield in tableviewcell for name , email, and phone number I want to show the error under the uitextfield when I press the button signup. so I create one label in xib I have hide it in xib swift function and know I want to show that label in under uitext when button pressed or if field is empty and we go to 2 nd one to edit we want to show the error message .  thank you

Comment: @Kuldeep Im using ACFloatingTextfield

Answer (score 1):

To show error messages, you can simply add a `UILabel` to the tableview cell and hide it by using `myLabel.isHidden = true` when there is no error.

Comment: When you are hiding the label that would leave an awkward gap between the labels.

Comment: ok. but I want to show the label when signup button pressed in table view cell.